# JpGraph page margin too narrow for large numbers

Tags: php, php-7, jpgraph

I have a little experience building graphs with `JpGraph` and I have never had this issue, simply because I have never dealt with numbers as large as the numbers I am dealing with currently.

The issue is that anything over **99,999** simply gets pushed off the left side of the graph.  I have tried to set the margin via `$graph->SetMargin();` to no avail.  I have poured through the documentation on the `jpgraph.net` yielding more questions than I have answers.  Here is an example image of what the graph is returning.

[image]

Put simply, I am at a loss ...  Can anyone offer insight as to how I can get this margin on the left hand side to display my graph correctly?  It is worth mentioning that I have tried numerous widths as an experiment, all the way up to 10,000 px wide, including a margin on the left side of more than 300px -- Still nothing. What am I missing?

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');

$datay1 = array(50,11000,110000,210000,320000,620000,860000,1200000,1500000,1200000,900000,700000,10000);
$datay3 = array(50,10000,100000,200000,300000,500000,600000,800000,1000000,950000,720000,510000,10000);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(600,300);
$graph->SetScale("intlin");
$graph->SetMargin(30,15,40,30);

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('0','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('To Meet Your Goal');

// Create the second line
$p3 = new LinePlot($datay3);
$graph->Add($p3);
$p3->SetColor("#FF1493");
$p3->SetLegend('Where You Stand');

$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(0);

// Output
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JpGraph margin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596443/jpgraph-margin-issue)

Comment: If you paid attention to my OP .. I used `setMargin` which was the answer for that "duplicate" ...

Comment: Still a dupe, maybe use a formatter for the axis scale data then (displaying 'k' instead of three trailing 0s).

Comment: You cannot display non numerical data in that field .. Already tried that ..

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. http://www.asial.co.jp/jpgraph/demo/src/Examples/show-example.php?target=datescaleticksex01.php